# Как задать два разных цвета одному элементу?

Tags: css, css3

Как задать два разных цвета одному элементу? Чтобы 50% занимаемой площади было красного цвета, а другая половина площади зелёной.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

градиентом

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, black 50%, blue 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще как вариант - использовать `:before(:after)`

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
}


div:nth-of-type(2):after{
  top: 0; left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div></div>
```